# React-js MUI Tooltip overlapping Popper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tooltip, popper.js

I want the MUI tooltip to go beneath the MUI Popper that is popper should overlap the tooltip. If I override the "MuiTooltip" or "MuiTooltip-popper"s z-index using external css, it's getting applied globally, which I don't want.

Is there a way to override either tooltip or popper behaviour & modify the z-index only for some portion ?

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-popper-issue-myryfv?file=/src/App.js

note: If the popper in the sandbox is not in the center, try to modify the code. Let the error appear & undo the modification.

I am using MUI v4

[image: Tooltip over Popper]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove external css and just add style prop to `Popper` component.

```
<Popper
   style={{
     zIndex: 1501
   }}
   anchorEl={buttonRef.current}
>
```